# Sortable elements where the handle sits outside the element to be dragged?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to make an element sortable and you drag its sub-elements using a handle BUT the handle is not a child of the sub-element?

For numerous reasons the drag handles will reside in the body element and not inside the element to be dragged. Will JQuery's sortable work this way?

Below is a simple example of what I would like to achieve (that does not work):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // How to associate a handle that sits outside the element to be dragged?
    $( ".elements" ).sortable({
     connectWith: ".elements",
     handle: ".handle"
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.handle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 64px;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="handle" target="foo">
  <span>+ FOO Handle</span>
</div>

<div class="handle" target="bar">
  <span>+ BAR Handle</span>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<div class="elements">
  <p id="foo">Foo</p>
  <p id="bar">Bar</p>
</div>
```